# How can i Call restFull API in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, plpython, plperl

I am using PostgreSQL 12.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit on Windows Server. And like to know how can I call RestFull API using python or perl in postgres.

I am relatively new in call restFull API from postgres so I will need a step by step guide on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather PostgreSQL works the same way as MariaDB and MySQL.

In python, you can use [this](https://github.com/AlexDev-py/postgresql_api) library to connect to your endpoints.
The readme provides a nice how-to for beginners to use.

Comment: I was hoping for a script that I could directly use in my postgreSQL function and then execute it from there directly instead of executing .py file
If I won't be to get the script then I will have to make do with the git link that you had shared me